# Apache NiFi 1.16.0 windows server closes immediately

Tags: windows, apache-nifi

I have recently installed NiFi 1.16.2 for windows and tried some requirement works when I try to restart the server it's throwing with the following error message.

**org.apache.nifi.controller.serialization.FlowSynchronizationException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot add Connection to Process Group because source is an Output Port that does not belong to a child Process Group**

```
org.apache.nifi.controller.serialization.FlowSynchronizationException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot add Connection to Process Group because source is an Output Port that does not belong to a child Process Group
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.serialization.VersionedFlowSynchronizer.synchronizeFlow(VersionedFlowSynchronizer.java:362)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.serialization.VersionedFlowSynchronizer.sync(VersionedFlowSynchronizer.java:185)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.serialization.StandardFlowSynchronizer.sync(StandardFlowSynchronizer.java:43)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.FlowController.synchronize(FlowController.java:1479)
    at org.apache.nifi.persistence.StandardFlowConfigurationDAO.load(StandardFlowConfigurationDAO.java:104)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardFlowService.loadFromBytes(StandardFlowService.java:815)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardFlowService.load(StandardFlowService.java:538)
    at org.apache.nifi.web.contextlistener.ApplicationStartupContextListener.contextInitialized(ApplicationStartupContextListener.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:1073)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:572)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.contextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:1002)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:746)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:379)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1449)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1414)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:916)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:288)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.doStart(GzipHandler.java:426)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:423)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer.start(JettyServer.java:1008)
    at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.<init>(NiFi.java:170)
    at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.<init>(NiFi.java:82)
    at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.main(NiFi.java:330)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot add Connection to Process Group because source is an Output Port that does not belong to a child Process Group
    at org.apache.nifi.groups.StandardProcessGroup.addConnection(StandardProcessGroup.java:1154)
    at org.apache.nifi.groups.StandardProcessGroupSynchronizer.addConnection(StandardProcessGroupSynchronizer.java:1853)
    at org.apache.nifi.groups.StandardProcessGroupSynchronizer.synchronizeConnections(StandardProcessGroupSynchronizer.java:531)
    at org.apache.nifi.groups.StandardProcessGroupSynchronizer.synchronize(StandardProcessGroupSynchronizer.java:388)
    at org.apache.nifi.groups.StandardProcessGroupSynchronizer.addProcessGroup(StandardProcessGroupSynchronizer.java:1019)
    at org.apache.nifi.groups.StandardProcessGroupSynchronizer.synchronizeChildGroups(StandardProcessGroupSynchronizer.java:423)
    at org.apache.nifi.groups.StandardProcessGroupSynchronizer.synchronize(StandardProcessGroupSynchronizer.java:373)
    at org.apache.nifi.groups.StandardProcessGroupSynchronizer.addProcessGroup(StandardProcessGroupSynchronizer.java:1019)
    at org.apache.nifi.groups.StandardProcessGroupSynchronizer.synchronizeChildGroups(StandardProcessGroupSynchronizer.java:423)
    at org.apache.nifi.groups.StandardProcessGroupSynchronizer.synchronize(StandardProcessGroupSynchronizer.java:373)
    at org.apache.nifi.groups.StandardProcessGroupSynchronizer.lambda$synchronize$0(StandardProcessGroupSynchronizer.java:221)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.flow.AbstractFlowManager.withParameterContextResolution(AbstractFlowManager.java:462)
    at org.apache.nifi.groups.StandardProcessGroupSynchronizer.synchronize(StandardProcessGroupSynchronizer.java:219)
    at org.apache.nifi.groups.StandardProcessGroup.synchronizeFlow(StandardProcessGroup.java:3830)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.serialization.VersionedFlowSynchronizer.synchronizeFlow(VersionedFlowSynchronizer.java:353)
    ... 45 common frames omitted
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by deleting files `C:\nifi-1.16.3\conf\flow.json.gz` and `C:\nifi-1.16.3\conf\flow.xml.gz`. Copied an older file from the folder "archive" `C:\nifi-1.16.3\conf\archive\20220816T121245+0300_flow.xml.gz` to the folder `C:\nifi-1.16.3\conf\` then rename it to `flow.json.gz`

Some of the data will be lost.

I created a bug report about this issue.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-10369